# Displaying Django model on template

Tags: python, django

Nothing is being displayed. even without any error log. although the model has data in it

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    cat = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    company_id = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
def list_products(request):
    object_list = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'object_list ': object_list})
```

index.html

```
   {% for e in object_list %}
      <li> {{ e.name }} </li>
   {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.list_products, name='index'),

]
```

Comment: Set your DEBUG=True in settings.py file so we see the error.

Comment: did you instert some data in your product table  !!

Comment: @AyoubBenayache that's a good point.

Comment: @AyoubBenayache sure, I even did this inside the view function to make sure that it is not empty ``` print(object_list[0].name)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix a typo in the render context:

```
{'object_list ': object_list}
```

make it

```
{'object_list': object_list}
```

You have and an extra " " whitespace after object_list key